# Can a oblique antiprism be constructed?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polyhedra, solid-geometry, polytopes

Can a oblique antiprism be constructed?

Intuitively, it would seem oblique antiprism exist: Take any right antiprism and translate one of the parallel faces within it's plane.

I'm baffled, though, because Google shows countless models and pictures of (right) antiprisms, but [not a single oblique antiprism](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oblique+antiprism%22).

If not: Are all antiprisms right? What are examples of non-right antiprisms?

---

## Update

I found [two drawings](https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/43400/43471/antip-non2_43471.htm) of [*skewed antiprisms*](https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/43400/43475/antip-oct3_43475.htm), which seems to be the same as what I called *oblique antiprisms*.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm having trouble visualizing that.  At the least, it would seem clear that a face perpendicular to the direction of translation could remain flat.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Can you please look at the drawings I posted? Do you agree they illustrate realizable oblique antiprisms with only planar (i.e. no curvature) faces?

Comment: These look correct to me. So you seem to have answered your own question. Please either delete it, or post your answer as an answer and accept it so the question does not remain on the unanswered queue.

Comment: @EthanBolker I did as you asked, but it doesn't allow me to accept my own answer within 2 days.  I do not think I should delete this question, as it is currently the best (only!) reference to oblique antiprisms available! Besides, others may have insight as to how to construct them or a proof of their existence (better than just a sketch).

Comment: Waiting two days is fine. Please [edit] the question to remove the answer, and paste the answer into the answer. What's there now is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the OP with sketches, but am baffled why I can find almost no reference, discussion, or models (when far more complicated polyhedra models abound), and have still not found a proof or construction of their existence (beyond a convincing sketch).

Comment: Those sketches are good enough for a proof. The top and bottom faces are planar. The other faces are all triangular, so planar.